# Create a Map of Map of Object from a given List of Object

Tags: kotlin

The structure of data class

```
data class ProductDetail(
  val name: String,
  val price: Int,
  val status: Status,
  val images: Images
...
)
```

I have a `List<ProductDetail>` and I want to convert it to `Map<String, Map<Int, ProductDetail>>`.

I tried looking into `associate` and `associatedTo` but I am only able to create `Map<String, Pair<Int, ProductDetail>>`. Is there a way to do this without the use to a loop in Kotlin?

Comment: What should be the String key of the outer map, and what should be the Int key of the inner maps?

Comment: @Tenfour04 `Map<name, Map<price, ProductDetail>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val mapOfMaps = list.groupBy(ProductDetail::name) // or { it.name }
    .mapValues { (name, productDetailsList) ->
        productDetailsList.groupBy(ProductDetail::price) // or { it.price }
    }
```

Use `groupBy` to easily create a map that groups items into matching lists. Then you can map those lists into inner maps with another `groupBy` call.

I am guessing `associate` is not the behavior you wanted here, because then every inner map would only contain one item, instead of all items with the matching `name`, and all repeated names would be dropped from the data.